# html ajax call node mongodb failed

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, call

HI I would like to use html ajax call mongodb and populate the results into my html

client html (dbajax.html):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/db',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsonp', // mongod is expecting the parameter name to be called "jsonp"})
```

Server
dbserver.js

```
http.createServer(function (request,response)
{  
    // serve site
    if (request.url === "/")
    {
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
    }
  if (request.url === "/db")
    {
       console.log("db");
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb2", function (err, db) {

       db.collection('Persons', function (err, collection) {

     collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        if(err) throw err;    
        console.log(items);    
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type:": "application/json"}); 
        var submittedPost = {};
        submittedPost['message'] = 'Proof that Node and Mongo are          working..';
        response.write( "_wrapper('" );
        response.write( JSON.stringify(items) );
        response.write( "')");              
        response.end();
    });

});

}); 
    }
      if (request.url === "/dbcall"){
          console.log("dbcall");
           fs.readFile('./dbajax.html', function (err, html) 
      {
        //response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
       response.write(html);  
       response.end();
    }
                )


  }
    //response.end(); 
}).listen(9000);
```

I type http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/dbcall  it calls dbajax.html but nothing happen further.
I assume the html ajax will call http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/db and return the JSON result.

So what is wrong?  I don't want to use Express and other frameworks.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple reasons for the missing response. You don't handle the error condition of `db.collection('Persons', ...)`. You should check if the `err` is filled here. And I suggest to add some `console.log()` statements at different points to see how far you get.

EDIT: I mixed up the URL you are calling but the hints above are still valid. But you should also handle the possible `err` condition of `fs.readFile(...)`.

You can also add some log statements to your `dbajax.html` to watch the progress within the developer console of your browser (you can open it by pressing F12).

Comment: Hello, OK but do you think the logic of my code is correct?  I am quite new in node.js so I am not sure it is a right way or not.

Comment: Generally your logic is OK. I think you only gave an excerpt of your application. Some parts as `submittedPost`seem unnecessary. And if you really don't want to use express and other helpful frameworks then that's the way to go.

Comment: I change the datatype to 'text', and it works suddenly.  how come?
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'text',
  jsonp: 'text',